# Why is opencv's moveWindow command inconsistent?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have four windows that I'm trying to place in a single row on my screen, using OpenCV (version 4.1.0) in Python (version 3.7.3). The relevant portion of the code I'm using is:

```
import cv2

cv2.namedWindow("Img 1")
cv2.namedWindow("Img 2")
cv2.namedWindow("Img 3")
cv2.namedWindow("Img 4")

cv2.moveWindow("Img 1", 10, 250)
cv2.moveWindow("Img 2", 400, 250)
cv2.moveWindow("Img 3", 800, 250)
cv2.moveWindow("Img 4", 1200, 250)

cv2.imshow("Img 1", img1[:,:,::-1])
cv2.imshow("Img 2", img2[:,:,::-1])
cv2.imshow("Img 3", img3[:,:,::-1])
cv2.imshow("Img 4", img4[:,:,::-1])

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

However, I never get all 4 windows in the same row. Sometimes I get the 2nd - 4th slightly higher than the first window; sometimes the 3rd and 4th are slightly higher than the 1st and 2nd windows, and sometimes the 4th window is the highest. The height error always seems to be about equal to the height of the windows' title bars.

Why aren't all 4 windows placed on row=250? Why doesn't openCV position them the same way everytime?

Comment: Works ok for me on Linux. All the windows line up. Maybe Windows specific?

Comment: @patthoyts - Not Windows issue, I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. I am running from inside Emacs, though. Could that be the problem????

Comment: Emacs also works for me. This is likely to be your window manager. A window only gets to provide hints to a window manager. My system is XFCE so xfwm4 is the window manager.

Comment: @patthoyts - Just checked w/ `wmctrl -m`. I'm running GNOME Shell. I'll Google around to see if any known issues 'tween it and OpenCV

Comment: OpenCV's GUI functionality is not great, and is mostly available for debugging purposes. I would not rely on it. If you want them all on the same row reliably, the easiest thing to do is concat all the images together horizontally.